# How to put round() inside regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I have a huge .json file which contains multiple info, I need to round numbers only in parameter of "heightroof".

I am using Regex and I have `heightroof": "(.*?)"` expression to find what I need. I am able to search for "heightroof": "(.*?)" and replace with "height": \1 using regex in Emeditor and it will make it work but I can't round numbers.But I also need to round numbers after "heightroof".

Instead of this:

```
 "heightroof": "21.3423423",
```

I need this:

```
 "height": 21,
```

Please help me round the numbers.

Comment: Use `"heightroof": "([^.]*)"` to stop when dot is encountered... but I would rather parse json properly instead, so you can round 21.8 to 22 not truncate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a callback to do this
Use `re.sub('rx',lambda m => {} )` form

Rx

`"(height)roof"\s*:\s*"(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)",`

Then in the callback convert `m[2]` to a float, round up, then take the integer portion
make it a string, then  return using the string parts `"` + m[1] + `":"` + round + `",`
etc...

Answer (score 0):

sin is correct in that you need a callback function.

```
import re

s = '"heightroof": "21.3423423"'

def repl(m):
    return '"height": ' + str(round(float(m.group(1))))

re.sub(r'"heightroof": "([^"]+)"', repl, s)

'"height": 21'
```